# Checking that I'm finding these adjoint operators correctly.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

I did exercise 2.1 (b) below. Am self-studying, and no answers in this book so I just want to make sure I'm finding the adjoint operator correctly. Thanks. And sorry for the glare.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Applications of Green's Functions in Science and Engineering by Michael D. Greenberg